# Как отобразить маршрут на карте Google в приложении Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

В приложении есть карта и возможность прокладки маршрута. Но как маршрут отобразить на этой карте ума не приложу. Весь Api reference уже облазил да и поисковики ничем помочь не могут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочтите внимательно ответ на [аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/) и сам вопрос тоже. Там всё разжёвано. Не пугайтесь, что в начале принятого ответа идут примеры для J2ME.. в продолжении объяснение для Android. Там ровно то, что вам нужно.